# If $X\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and $x\in X$ is an isolated point, then $x$ is a cluster point of $X^c$

Tags: real-analysis

If $X\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ and $x\in X$ is an isolated point, then $x$ is a cluster point of $X^c$.

I don't know if that is true or not, can someone help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

$x\in X$ is isolated means that there exists open $U\ni x$ such that $U\cap X=\{x\}$. But $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open implies there exits $r>0$ such that $B_r(x)\subset U$. But $B_r(x)\cap (\mathbb{R}^n\setminus X)=B_r(x)\setminus \{x\}$.

Comment: Hi, thank you..so this is true?

Comment: Absolutely. From here, you can find many sequences that are contained in $X^C$ that converge to $x$

Comment: From Adam's argument, we have $B_{r'}(x) \cap X^c = B_{r'}(x) \setminus \{x\} $ whenever $0 < r' \leq r$. If $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and if $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, we say that $x$ is a cluster (or limit, or accumulation) point of $A$ if for every $\varepsilon>0$ the open ball $B_{\varepsilon}(x)$ intersects $A \setminus \{x\}$. So given $r'>0$,  do you know if $B_{r'}(x) \setminus \{x\} $ is nonempty (in the context of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the standard topology)?

Comment: Ok, thank you!! $U$ is open set in $X$?

Comment: Yes. This is the definition of $x\in X$ being isolated. At least, it is one definition. Depending on the course you see it in, you may see a different (but equivalent) definition

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is a cluster point, then, there is an open set $U\subset X^c\cup\{x\}$ s.t. $U\cap \{x\}=\{x\}$. Let $\delta >0$ s.t. $]x,x+\delta [\subset U$. Let $n$ big enough to have $\frac{1}{N}<\delta $. Then $x_n=x+\frac{1}{n}$ where $n\geq N$ is a sequence of $X^c$ that converges to $x$.